# A problem in probability with independent events .

Tags: probability

A forest has a fire per year with probability $30\%$ and it has 2 fires per year with possibility $5\%$ .The probability of 3 or more fires is $0\%$.The forest might have disasters from the wind which blows with probability of $100\%$ or has disasters from the fire with probability $25\%$.If the disasters from the wind are independent from the disasters caused by the fire ,then find the probability of the disasters in the forest per year .

$F_{1}: $ the event of one fire

$F_{2}:$ the event of two fires

$D:$ the event of disasters

$W:$ the event of the wind

$F:$ the event of fire

I think that $P(D)=P(D/W)\cdot P(W)+P(D/F)\cdot P(F)$ , but I'm not sure for that and I dont know how to use the fact that the distasters of the wind are independent from the disasters caused by the fire .Any ideas, please ??

Comment: Are "fires" and "disasters from fires" considered two separate things?

Comment: Is 100% the probability of the wind blowing, or the probability of a disaster from the wind? If it’s the former, then the question is missing the probability of a disaster from the wind. If it’s the latter, then the probability of a disaster from either the fire or wind is 100%, because the probability of a disaster from the wind is 100%

Comment: I put the events.The disasters of fire i mean P(D/F) so it is different from P(F).The probability of the wind is 100 per cent.The exersize was only the problem and i wrote the events.Any help please?